# How to access nested CDK resources, for testing?

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a CDK stack that's creating an ECS cluster, task definitions, services, ALB listeners, etc. I have tests to verify things in the stack are tagged correctly (for example). When I try to verify certain types, there are zero in the stack's resources.

For example:

```
template.allResources("AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition", {
  Properties: {
    Tags: Match.arrayWith([
      Match.objectLike({
        Key: "some-key",
        Value: "some-value",
      }),
    ]),
  },
});
```

This will result in a filed test with the message:

> One or more resources are missing common tags:
> AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition: Error: Template has 0 resource(s) with type AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition, but none match as expected.

I've debugged this by outputting the contents of the template, and indeed, there is no task definition within the resources. I assume it's nested under the cluster:

```
{
  Resources: {
    Bucket83908E77: ...,
    ...
    ClusterEB0386A7: ...
  },
}
```

How can I test nested resources?

Comment: Did you find the TaskDefinition resource in the template?

Comment: No, it's not in the template as far as I can tell. Unless it's nested somewhere. I am inspecting the template's resources via `template.toJSON().Resources`.

Comment: Inspect the actual synthesized template and determine for sure whether it's there or not.

Comment: The roles are created / are in the actual synthesis, I'm just not sure how to get there "via code".

Comment: The Task Definition, you mean? Do you see a resource with `"Type" : "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"` in the template?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal but reproducible code example? Also, your existing example contains `AWS::ECS:TaskDefinition` instead of `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition`, but the error specifies the latter. I'm assuming the code in the question is not correct.

Comment: `AWS::ECS:TaskDefinition` was a typo on my part here. And no, there is no such resource in the output of `template.toJSON().Resources`. Although the task def is certainly created when the stack is deployed. I assume the resource is nested under the cluster but I do not know how to get to it.

Comment: I meant the actual template in the `cdk.out` folder (or in the CloudFormation console)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal but reproducible code example?

Comment: Sorry, I hear you -- will do when I get a chance.